# Nested <div> borders won't stay inside the main <div> when input:checked

Tags: css

- I have a main  position: relative.
- Nested (input check box) position: absolute.
- When the checkbox is checked the inside div color will scale to 500px. The problem is the color will spill out its main .
- Here is the screen shot of the checkbox border spilling out of the main square . https://pasteboard.co/I7uA6am.jpg
- What I am trying to do is When we click the circle checkbox at the bottom right. The background color of that checkbox will fill the entire main  which is a rectangle of 300px by 400px. In this case the checkbox border takes almost the entire screen as it is set to 500px.

I have tried
- Z-index
- Setting the width of the box-shadow transform to 100% width of the main 
- overflow: hidden.
- position: absolute;

None of those solutions worked.

// HTML CODE //

```
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
     <div class="toggle">+</div>
        <div class="imgBox"> </div>
           <div class="content"> </div>
               <div class="details"> 

                 <h2>A quick check on CSS</h2>
                 <p> Just doing a quick test on CSS</p>


             </div>
</div>
```

// CSS CODE //

```
card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #262626;
}

input, 
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 10;
  }

  input {
  opacity: 0;
  }

.toggle {
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9c27b0;
  overflow: hidden;
   }
```

/* WHEN INPUT IS SET TO CHECK, TOGGLE APPEARS */

```
  input:checked ~ .toggle {

  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px #9c27b0;

  transform: rotate(500);
  }
```

Comment: Your question imo is very unclear. Please explain in detail what your desired result should look like

Comment: Hey there. Does this help ???  https://pasteboard.co/I7uA6am.jpg
Hope it clears it up, sorry if my question was confusing, will try to edit it in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand you would need `overflow:hidden` on the `.card`. please let me know if this is what you were looking for

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #262626;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input,
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle {
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9c27b0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input:checked~.toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px #9c27b0;
  transform: rotate(500);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
  <div class="toggle">+</div>
  <div class="imgBox"> </div>
  <div class="content"> </div>
  <div class="details">

    <h2>A quick check on CSS</h2>
    <p> Just doing a quick test on CSS</p>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this how you want it?

```css
card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #262626;
}

input,
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle {
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9c27b0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input:checked~.toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 300px #9c27b0;
  transform: rotate(500deg);
  background-color: #9c27b0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" name="">
  <div class="toggle">+</div>
  <div class="imgBox"> </div>
  <div class="content"> </div>
  <div class="details">

    <h2>A quick check on CSS</h2>
    <p> Just doing a quick test on CSS</p>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I uploaded a new screenshot explaining in more details.
Hope it helps and thanks for your time.

https://pasteboard.co/I7uA6am.jpg